# Manera más eficiente de obtener solo los elementos anteriores a una fecha determinada

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dispongo de un `DataFrame` de pandas, con dos columnas, una con un código de clientes y fechas.
Quiero saber qué clientes no han pedido en los últimos dos años, es decir aquellos que en un periodo en torno a 730 días no han aparecido en la lista.
A continuación propongo un modelo de código que podría servir de modelo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timdelta

fechas =[Timestamp ('2018-06-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2019-01-04 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2019-06-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2019-12-11 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2020-01-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2017-02-10 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2017-10-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2017-12-07 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2018-01-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2018-02-28 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2018-11-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2018-11-23 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2019-02-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2019-08-21 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2018-11-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2019-06-04 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2019-10-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2019-12-11 00:00:00'),Timestamp ('2019-11-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2020-01-03 00:00:00')]
clientes =[4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000003,4300000003, 4300000003, 4300000003, 4300000003, 4306000335, 4306000338,4306000638, 4306000915, 4306003799, 4306003800, 4306010278, 4306010278,4306010521, 4306010521]
#el array en cuetion
list_clients = pd.DataFrame ({ 'cliente': clientes, 'fecha':fechas }

)
#calculo la fecha a partir de la cual han pasado los 2 aC1os desde hoy
flag_date = today - timedelta (days = 730)
#arrays para rellenar dos grupos, los elementos anteriores y los posteriores a esa fecha
before =[]
after =[]
#elementos anteriores a esta fecha y posteriores son clasificados
for i, val in enumerate (list_clients['fecha']):
    if val<flag_date:
        before.append (list_clients['cliente'][i])
    else:
        after.append (list_clients['cliente'][i])
#los transformo en DataFrame para despues trabajar con grupos
before = pd.DataFrame ({'before':before})
after = pd.DataFrame ({'after':after})

#aqui dejo solo los elementos que esten antes de esa fecha y no esten en el otro grupo
difference = pd.concat ([before, after, after]).drop_duplicates (keep = False)
print (len (difference['before']))
```

Este es mi calculo, sin embargo no estoy seguro de que sea ni optimo, ni que el resultado sea correcto. Gracias por vuestros aportes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy simple es filtrar aquellas filas con fecha superior o igual a la límite. Esto se puede hacer con un simple filtro boleano comparando la columna con fechas y  `flag_date`. De esas filas solo queremos los clientes y eliminamos duplicados. Estos serían los clientes que han comprado al menos una vez en los dos últimos años.

Para obtener el resto solo hay que usar `pandas.Series.isin` y obtener aquellos clientes de la columna que no están en la serie anterior:

```
import pandas as pd



fechas =[pd.Timestamp ('2018-06-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2019-01-04 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2019-06-19 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2019-12-11 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2020-01-23 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2017-02-10 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2017-10-19 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2017-12-07 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2018-01-19 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2018-02-28 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2018-11-20 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2018-11-23 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2019-02-07 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2019-08-21 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2018-11-27 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2019-06-04 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2019-10-29 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2019-12-11 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp ('2019-11-12 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp ('2020-01-03 00:00:00')]

clientes =[4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000001, 4300000003, 4300000003,
           4300000003, 4300000003, 4300000003, 4306000335, 4306000338,4306000638, 4306000915,
           4306003799, 4306003800, 4306010278, 4306010278, 4306010521, 4306010521]


list_clients = pd.DataFrame({'cliente': clientes, 'fecha':fechas})

# Calculamos la fecha a partir de la cual han pasado los 2 años desde hoy
flag_date = pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('2Y')
# Serie con los clientes sin duplicados
uniq_clients = list_clients["cliente"].drop_duplicates()

# Serie con clientes que compraron en los dos últimos años
after = list_clients.loc[list_clients["fecha"] >= flag_date, "cliente"]
after.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# Serie con el resto
before = uniq_clients[~uniq_clients.isin(after)]
before.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

# Si quieres dataframes
before = pd.DataFrame ({'before': before})
after = pd.DataFrame ({'after': after})
```

> ```
> >>> before
>       before
> 0     4300000003
>
> >>> after
>       after
> 0     4300000001
> 10    4306000335
> 11    4306000338
> 12    4306000638
> 13    4306000915
> 14    4306003799
> 15    4306003800
> 16    4306010278
> 18    4306010521
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y a demás es mas rapido que mi solución